# How to require password if single-user mode is selected Solaris 11?

Tags: solaris, login, password

I want to demand root password when running single-user mode on Solaris 11. Unfortunately any of the guides seem to work in my case.

The `/etc/default/sulogin` is commented as required, uncommenting and changing to `PASSREQ=YES` doesn't do anything either.

Help appreciated